# Trim csv cell string with Powershell

Tags: arrays, string, shell, powershell, csv

I am having trouble using the .Trim() function on a column within a csv file. This csv file only contains one column in the whole table so it should be pretty straight forward (he says).

The data within my csv, Exhibit A (**NOTE: This is all in one field/column, not separate columns**):

```
Name
C:\Users\kgroome\Documents\NOC\Documentation\Chrome, .pdf
C:\Users\kgroome\Documents\NOC\Documentation\CLI, .docx
C:\Users\kgroome\Documents\NOC\Documentation\DNS, .pdf
C:\Users\kgroome\Documents\NOC\Documentation\Encryption, .pdf
C:\Users\kgroome\Documents\NOC\Documentation\Excel, .xlsx
```

Ideally I need to trim everything from right to left after the final 5 characters within the string OR split after the `,` as this would be much more ideal

What I currently have in regards to syntax for splitting after the `,` is the following:

```
$data = Import-Csv "C:\Support\Test05.csv"

foreach($line in $data){

    $line.split(',')[5].Trim(); |

    Export-Csv -Path "C:\Support\Test06.csv"

 }
```

Albeit this isn't my best, I have had previous syntax for both methods however I have scrapped it because it was near useless.

Your help would be extremely appreciated so I can know why I am going wrong!

Comment: The `Split()` method creates an array.  That means `$line.split(',')[5]` means "the sixth item of the array after splitting on commas," which is almost certainly a null value here.  I'm also confused why you're importing a text file to CSV and then immediately saving something else to the same variable, or why your CSV has only one field header but appears to have two fields.  Is the comma actual data?

Comment: Apologies here @BaconBits , I have not copy and pasted my correct syntax, I have amended this now having you point out that I have essentially created a "double variable" which is useless. In regards to my CSV it does indeed only have one field header but the data is all in one column, they are not separate fields/columns so to answer your question, yes the `,` and any data after that is actually data in the first field.

Comment: I am not clear on your expected output. Do you just want what is infront of the comma and drop what is after? `Import-Csv` creates an object array but you are treating it like a string array

Comment: @Matt pretty much, anything after the `,` is what my expected outcome wants to be. Would you suggest a `get-content` and `set-content` clause instead to avoid treating the object array as a string array?

Comment: Your example doe not make sense, you want to split a line on a comma but you are using Import-Csv which will do that for you. Your example has a variable called $line - where did that come from?

Comment: @DaveSexton It's all in one column/field Dave, as I mentioned on my topic post so using `Import-Csv` will not split it for me. And it came from my foreach loop statement:

`foreach($line in $data){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm only suggesting this to help you understand where your code was not functioning properly. I am still not *completely* sure what your output is supposed to look like and there are better ways to do this (like with regex)

```
$file = "c:\temp\text.csv"
$newfile = "c:\temp\text1.csv"

Get-Content $File | ForEach-Object{
    If($_ -match ","){
        $_.Split(",").Trim()[1]
    } Else {
        $_
    }
} | Set-Content $newfile
```

Output

```
Name
.pdf
.docx
.pdf
.pdf
.xlsx
```

Split creates an array from a string based on the delimiter you specify. Splitting on a comma with your sample data will only create an array with *two* elements. Requesting the sixth element with `5` will simply generate a null.

As for a regex solution this would suffice and generate the same output in the original file.

```
(Get-Content $File) -replace ".*,\s?" | Set-Content $file
```

The regex here would grab all characters up until the comma as well as the following space if present. Since the match requires the comma to be there the first row with "Name" is skipped as it does not match.

Comment: Thanks so much for your input Matt, you have helped me understand a lot clearer where my code has gone wrong in terms of using the Split function & the `Foreach-Object` function is a lot more effective than using a loop. Also the `Regex` solution is fantastic which I didn't know existed and now I will be utilizing this a lot more in the future! I really appreciate you helping me with my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are using a CSV file is a bit of a red herring and I think you want to use replace insread of split:

```
Get-Content "C:\Support\Test05.csv" | % {
    $_ -replace '\s*,\s*', ','
} | Set-Content "C:\Support\Test06.csv"
```

Comment: This worked! thank you ever so much for your time. The -Replace switch really works a lot better than the .split function, which I now know exists :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this:

```
gc "C:\Support\Test05.csv" | 
        % { $_.split(',')[-1].trim()} | 
                 set-content "C:\Support\Test06.csv"
```

Comment: This also worked well! thank you ever so much for your time and helping me understanding the split method.